# Волосянистая или волосенистая поверхность, ткань, материя?

Tags: грамматика

Волосянистая или волосенистая поверхность, ткань, материя?

Answer (score 3):

> Волосянистая или волосенистая?

Верен первый вариант. См.:

[***волосян***(ой)](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x) + суффикс ***-ист*** +окончание ***-ый = волосянистый.***

> [***-ист***-(ый)](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136201)
>
> суффикс
>
> Словообразовательная единица, образующая имена прилагательные с общим
>   значением обладания чем-либо - нередко в большом количестве - или
>   склонности к чему-либо, названному словами, от которых соответствующие
>   имена прилагательные образованы
>
> <…>
>
> 2) содержащий в большом количестве то, имеющий примесь того или
>   напоминающий то, что названо образующим прилагательным *(водяни́стый,
>   масляни́стый, мучни́стый, слюдяни́стый, смоляни́стый и т.п.)*